Python3 pickle: Expected type 'SupportsWrite[bytes]', got 'BinaryIO' instead
A simple program in PyCharm 2024.2.3.(Community Edition)
import pickle

fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'banana']

with open('myData.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(fruits, f)

PyCharm gives me a warning:

Expected type 'SupportsWrite[bytes]', got 'BinaryIO' instead

The program runs correctly, but how do I get rid of this warning?
Python tutorials say that this simple usage of pickle should work.

My advice would be to just ignore that warning.

I reported this upstream.

The warning is erroneous. You can suppress it as follows:
import pickle

fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'banana']

with open('myData.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    # noinspection PyTypeChecker
    pickle.dump(fruits, f)

Note:
This is specific to PyCharm

The issue is a type hint issue, but it's not an error. To solve the warning, you can use BinaryIO. I provide code for it. It will solve the warning.
import pickle
from typing import cast, BinaryIO

fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'banana']

with open('myData.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    f = cast(BinaryIO, f)
    pickle.dump(fruits, f)

Hope it helps you.

@RonLat, can you try again? I just updated my answer

You should not add code just to hide erroneous warnings. The code is OK, PyCharm is wrong.
